# Recipe for "warning screen" + go back

Tags: docassemble

I'm trying to implement a "that feature not yet supported" screen. I imagine there are many such "offramp" screens in a number of apps. I did look through the recipies section of the docs, but I didn't see anything.

Ideally, I want the user to be able to, from that screen (1) go back to the question that set `variable` leading them to the screen, or (2) exit the interview.

I would also like `variable` to be reset, so the question is re-asked.

Something like this, I would think?

```
---
id: problematic_question
# sets the value of var
---
mandatory: True
code: |
    if var == "x":
        undefine("var") # not sure if undefine() or forget_result_of('problematic_question') would be better here, or if they're perhaps equivalent for this use case [or if I'm completely off]
        force_ask("event_not_supported")
---
event: event_not_supported
question: (!!!) This option not supported
buttons:
  - Go back: refresh # if I understand correctly, undefining var, in conjunction with refresh, should take the user back to problematic_question
  - Exit: leave
---
```

I am running into a problem where I'm getting an infinite loop, where DA is attempting to define `event_not_supported`. I'm also not sure if my general approach would achieve the result / flow I want.

Help would be appreciated:

1. Is there a standard way off approaching such "off ramps"
2. Is there any reason, based on the example above, that an infinite loop should be occurring (presumably, DA is not actually undefining `variable` as expected, and thus continuously seeking the definition of `event_not_supported`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`force_ask()`](https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#force_ask) has some different behaviors that are only useful under special circumstances. My way of approaching off-ramps is to use the normal logic flow. Something like:

```yaml
---
id: problematic_question
# sets the value of my_var
---
mandatory: True
code: |
  if my_var == "x":
    event_not_supported
---
event: event_not_supported
question: (!!!) This option not supported
back button: True
buttons:
  - Exit: exit
    url: https://example.com
---
```

The `back button` attribute will make sure to show the usual back button. Hitting 'Back' will let the user redefine the value for `my_var`, so there won't be a reason to `undefine()` it. `exit` is a special button value (https://docassemble.org/docs/questions.html#special%20buttons).

> `exit` means that the user’s variable store will be erased and the user will be redirected either to the URL given by the associated `url` text, or if no `url` is defined, to the [exit url](https://docassemble.org/docs/initial.html#exit%20url) defined in the [metadata](https://docassemble.org/docs/initial.html#metadata), or if that does not defined, then to the [exitpage](https://docassemble.org/docs/config.html#exitpage) defined in the [configuration](https://docassemble.org/docs/config.html). If the user tries to come back to the interview again, he will start the interview again, as though it had never been started. Original URL parameters will be lost.

<del>As for the infinite loop, the docs say</del>

> Note also that no code that comes after `force_ask()` will ever be executed.

<del>The phrasing is a bit confusing in a case like this, but I believe that it also means nothing more will be run for this code - neither code before nor code after will get triggered anymore. That block, the logic flow that brought you to the code `force_ask()`, is done once you trigger `force_ask()`.</del>

Sorry, my mistake about the infinite loop. The behavior I was remembering was old behavior. Is there other code that you haven't included here?

Comment: This works great - not sure what the issue was before. My experience is that typos tend to be at fault when I get really weird behavior and I can't figure it out.